# QGIS: Create New Relationship gdb vs. gpkg

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, geopackage, spatial-relationship

I'm looking for an option to store different relationships directly in the database. When I add the gdb/gpkg into a project the relationships should be loaded automatically too.
For a gdb I can choose between different cardinalities, but with a gpkg I can only choose many-to-many relationship. Why is this the case? Am I missing any preprocessing work when using gpkg? I would also like to choose the cardinality when using gpkg.

[image]

gdb:

[image]

gpkg:

[image]